# runtime '13' Data type mismatch

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, type-mismatch

So I have this code which is used to set the stage for a public function:

```
Private Sub OrderMatbtn_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim lngPartID As Long
   Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset
   Dim lngEstID As Long
   Dim dblQty As Double

   'Set the Estimate ID to the current Estimate
   lngEstID = Me.EstID

   'Open the Estimate detail as a recordset filtered on lngEstID
   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblEstDtl.PartID, tblEstDtl.Qty, " _
          & "tblEstDtl.EstID FROM tblEstDtl " _
          & "WHERE tblEstDtl.EstID = " & lngEstID)

'The rest of the code
```

And I am getting a data type mismatch error on the `Set rs` line. I have checked `tblEstDtl.EstId` and it is set to Long. Is my error somehow with the `db.OpenRecordset`? I am new to VBA. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT It seems to be a problem with `Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet` because even when I use the simple string:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblEstDtl.* FROM tblEstDtl;")
```

it still gives me the same error.

EDIT 2 Well I changed my Declarations to look like this:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim lngPartID As Long
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngEstID As Long
Dim dblQty As Double
```

Adding the DAO. to db and rs. I wasn't sure if I should post this as an answer or not because I still don't know why I had to do this.

Comment: if you run the sql in an access query does it work? And what is value of lngEstID when you pass into SQL statement?

Comment: Not sure that it'll fix your issue, because it's probably done implicitly, but try `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ... = " & CStr(lngEstID) )`

Comment: Yes, it works in a regular query. What exactly do you mean by the value of lngEstID?(remember I am new to VBA) The value is set to equal Me.EstID. Should the variable be declared as a String instead of Long Int because it is being used to make up a string?

Comment: I put in `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblEstDtl.PartID, tblEstDtl.Qty, tblEstDtl.EstID FROM tblEstDtl " _
       & "WHERE tblEstDtl.EstID = " & CStr(lngEstID))` and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: put "debug.print Me.EstID: stop"  in the code before you hit the code before you get the error.  run the code, what is in the immediates window?

Comment: There is a   10  in the immediate window.

Comment: Try using **Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblEstDtl.* FROM tblEstDtl;", dbOpenSnapShot)**

Comment: DAO is the answer because you also have a (not needed) reference to ADO, thus Access gets confused.

Comment: Should I or do I need to change something in regards DAO or ADO to help me in the future?

Comment: On a side note and unrelated to the problem - you can remove the table name from each field in your query as there's only one table.  You only need to explicitly state the table name if the field appears in more than one table in your query.  So `SELECT PartID, Qty, EstID FROM tblEstDtl WHERE EstID = ` will work.

Comment: Thank you Darren